# Why i can access outer non final variable from a local method inner class

Tags: java

When my friend runs this code. It reports a compile error says it315 has to be final which it is same as the books says. However when i run it in my  eclipse it has no problem at all. I can access it315 even though it is not final.  I just wonder why.

```
public class InOut {

    String str=new String("between");

    public void amethod(final int iArgs){

        int it315= 10；
        class Bicycle{
            public void sayHello(){
                System.out.println(str);
                System.err.println(iArgs);
                System.out.println(it315);
            }


        }
        Bicycle  cBicycle=new Bicycle();
        cBicycle.sayHello();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new InOut ().amethod(999);

    }

}
```

Comment: You mean: 'When my friend _compiles_ this code', don't you?

Comment: Yes. He cant compile this code. It reports the error that it canot access to non final variable

Comment: Which Java version are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8 you can access "effectively final" variables (which are not declared final, but actually not modified). Seems that your friend is using Java 7 (or older) compiler while your Eclipse installation is configured to use Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

reason is, to avoid value change of that variable, while inner class is accessing that variable. 
compiler copy the values of variable to inner class variables that's why.

as for as why your friend got error concerns, i guess, @Tagir answer is logical,